# Can I pass data through the next function in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

In using `Express`, I have a route like:

```
app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
  // no route is matched
  // so call next() to pass to the static middleware
  next();
});
```

There's another route that is something like `app.get('/myroute', function(req, res, next)...`

Can I pass information through to that route from the first one via `next`?

Comment: I believe you can use res.locals for passing data within a single route processing chain

Comment: `app.locals` or `req.locals`

Comment: `req.locals.requestTimestamp = microtime.now()` gives me: `500 TypeError: Cannot set property 'requestTimestamp' of undefined`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks @amakhrov. I can use `res.locals` and store information.